# Why filtering in SLD file doesn't work when applied to shapefiles?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapserver, sld, filter

I have downloaded shapefiles from OpenStreetMap and I want to give styling using SLD files so that the map looks like OpenStreetMap.  The GIS tool I use is MapServer. I got some SLDs from the following link:

https://github.com/mitchelljj/openstreetmap-sld

But the problem is that when filtering is applied to give different styles to motorway, trunk roads, streets etc. (in case of roads), it doesn't work. Without filtering it will work, but it will give same styling to all kinds of roads (and obviously the map won't look like OpenStreetMap). The below is an example of filter that doesn't work:

```
 <ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:Or>
      <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    <ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Literal>motorway</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    <ogc:PropertyName>highway</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Literal>trunk</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    </ogc:Or>
  </ogc:Filter>
```

Can anybody throw some light on this?

Comment: Is the attribute in your shapefile actually HIGHWAY instead of highway?

Comment: When you say doesn't work, do you mean you get a blank image?

Comment: Have you tried zooming in? I see some of the styles have minimum and maximum scales applied - if you have a blank map that could be it.

Comment: "so that the map looks like OpenStreetMap" presumably means "so that the map looks like a commonly used map rendering of OSM data"?  If so, it's probably worth mentioning that at most zoom levels that style reads from a database rather than from shapefiles.  Or have I got hold of the wrong end of the stick here?

Comment: @nmtoken   yes. exactly, a blank image comes. But its not because of scaling since I tried with not  adding any min and max scales. Thank you.

Comment: @StevenKay I have checked with not giving any max and min scales as well as zooming in to different levels but without any luck. Thanku.

Comment: @SomeoneElse thnks for the info. Am I wrong that styles are applied to shapefiles irrespective of zoom levels?

Comment: @IanTurton Since I have downloaded shapefiles from open street map, the attribute should be as per osm data listed in http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway. So it is highway only if i'm not wrong. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: please run ogrinfo on the shapefile just to be sure of the attribute names

Comment: Only so much info available.  
ogrinfo -ro -so roads.shp  
 INFO: Open of `roads.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Comment: @Akhil I was trying to explain how the maps that you see at OpenStreetMap.org are rendered (they don't use MapServer).

Comment: How are you passing the SLD to MapServer, is it SLD_BODY or SLD parameters in the GetMap request? MapServer AFAIK doesn't use SLD as part of its internal configuration to apply any style.